What determines how wide are the absorption spectrum lines of atoms?
So let's assume we have atoms in their ground state and we measure what kind of wavelengths those atoms can absorb. These should occur at photon energies that correspond the the energy gaps between the ground state and the various exited states of the atom. Now the ground state and the exited states have (in principle) precisely defined energies. If one thinks about it simplistically, it would seem the absorption lines would have to be infinitely thin which would also imply that the atoms would only absorb an infinitely small portion of incoming broad spectrum light. Of course, that doesn't sound right and it's not what we observe. So how wide are the lines and why?
Then some thoughts.
Doppler broadening
It's fairly obvious that the thermal movement of the atoms should widen the absorption lines. This is easy to understand and you don't need to explain that part to me. However, that probably can't be the only explanation. Surely, even cold matter wouldn't have infinitely thing absorption lines. Also, even with Doppler broadening, the simplistic way of thinking would still lead one to the conclusion that only an infinitely small portion of light would be absorbed because an absorbed photon would still have to have the correct energy when taking into account the velocity of the absorbing atom.
Let's assume we are e.g. measuring the absorption spectrum of a very cold and very sparse gas (so that atomic collisions don't broaden the lines either). Or we could think about measuring the absorption cross-section of an individual atom at different frequencies. We can say that an absorption line is at a frequency where the absorption cross-section has a local maximum and the width of it comes from how far away the absorption cross-section drops to e.g. $1/2$ of the maximum. Maybe that kind of experiment would be too difficult in practice but we can still use it as thought experiment.
Then some further thoughts.
Uncertainty principle
I suspect this is the real explanation but I would like to know more. The absorption energies shouldn't be exactly defined unless the absorption process takes infinitely long. However, it's not clear to me what the time scale for absorption is. Also, this should only give a minimum for the width of an absorption line, not a maximum.
So how could we calculate the widths of the absorption lines, at least in principle?

Spectral line shape

Somehow related Existence of monochromatic pulses?
